# sign in with linkedin not working in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I am integrating sign in with linked-in by using the JavaScript SDK.It seems to work fine in google chrome but on internet explorer it does not work.It just opens a blank window but does not display anything.

Can anyone help with this issue ?